# Sort only one value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I sort banana after apple always?

```
    arr = [
          { 'id' : 1, 'fruit' : 'apple' },
          { 'id' : 2, 'fruit' : 'banana' },
          { 'id' : 3, 'fruit' : 'custard' },
          { 'id' : 4, 'fruit' : 'banana' },
          { 'id' : 5, 'fruit' : 'apple' },
          { 'id' : 6, 'fruit' : 'custard' } 
        ];
```

expected:

```
      arr = [
          { 'id' : 1, 'fruit' : 'apple' },
          { 'id' : 3, 'fruit' : 'custard' },
          { 'id' : 5, 'fruit' : 'apple' },
          { 'id' : 2, 'fruit' : 'banana' },
          { 'id' : 4, 'fruit' : 'banana' },
          { 'id' : 6, 'fruit' : 'custard' } 
        ];
```

So banana should always appear after apple, or apple should be sorted before banana.

this is what i've tried:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
      return (a.fruit === 'banana') - (b.fruit === 'banana') 
})
```

but in this case, banana always gets sorted at the end of the array, which is not what i'm going for. all the 'banana' items should be automatically sorted after the last 'apple' item

Comment: split the arrays in parts before apple and after, and you apply the sort on the array that you want

Comment: Why not just sort by item2?

Comment: We need to understand data structure and it's  purpose too, so we can give you good (or even optimal) solution/suggestion. So, for example why you have object where `item1` key holds some kind of an id, and `item2` hold a name. It's kinda strange data structure that doesn't make too much of a sense.

Comment: modified my question to include these^

Comment: @trincot i would do that, but i'm not looking for the values to be sorted in alphabetical order.

Comment: So, basically  you just  need  to logic where `apple` is first, and `banana` is second? And that's it? Nothing will change for other items? No sorting applied to other items?

Comment: yes the other items should not be sorted

Comment: basically - all the 'banana' items should be automatically sorted after the last 'apple' item

Comment: Is it important that `apple` needs to be at the top (first item in an array) of an array? Or you could have in in the 10th position, and then banana should take the 11th place?

Comment: Why not ["apple", "apple", "custard", "banana",  "banana", "custard"]?

Comment: yes the latter. apple shouldnt be sorted to be at the top.

Comment: Why was "custard" moved from index 2 to index 1 in your desired output? What is the logic?

Comment: @loraine, could you please take a look at my comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply sort by `item2` (alphabetically).

```
arr.sort((a, b) => a.item2.localeCompare(b.item2));
```

This will put all records in alphabetical order based on `item2`.

If however you want to perform the minimum number of swaps, then I suggest you don't use `sort`, but loop the array by bringing two indices towards each other starting at both ends:

```js
let arr = [
      { 'item1' : 1, 'item2' : 'apple' },
      { 'item1' : 2, 'item2' : 'banana' },
      { 'item1' : 3, 'item2' : 'custard' },
      { 'item1' : 4, 'item2' : 'banana' },
      { 'item1' : 5, 'item2' : 'apple' },
      { 'item1' : 6, 'item2' : 'custard' } 
];

let i = 0;
let j = arr.length-1;
while (true) {
    while (i < j && arr[i].item2 !== "banana") {
        i++;
    }
    while (i < j && arr[j].item2 !== "apple") {
        j--;
    }
    if (i >= j) {
        break;
    }
    [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]]; // swap
    i++;
    j--;
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: You're welcome. To make the question clearer, and useful for future visitors, could you edit it and mention exactly what the goal is? Is it to minimise the number of swaps? Because honestly, the first naive sort-solution I gave is also putting all banana entries after the apple entries. There are many outcomes that do that. But apparently you have more rules/constraints in mind than what you told us in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This will in a first step separate the array into two: `res[true]` containing all the "banana"-elements and `res[false]` all the others. In a second step the array `res[true]` is `.splice()`-ed into the `res[false]` array after the last index of "apple".

```js
const arr = [
      { 'item1' : 1, 'item2' : 'apple' },
      { 'item1' : 2, 'item2' : 'banana' },
      { 'item1' : 3, 'item2' : 'custard' },
      { 'item1' : 4, 'item2' : 'banana' },
      { 'item1' : 5, 'item2' : 'apple' },
      { 'item1' : 6, 'item2' : 'custard' } 
    ];

let res=arr.reduce(
  (a,c)=>(a[c.item2==="banana"].push(c),a),
  {true:[],false:[]} );
  
let pos=res[false].map(e=>e.item2).lastIndexOf("apple")+1;
// in case "apple" was not found: simply copy arr:
res=pos?(res[false].splice(pos,0,...res[true]),res[false]):arr.slice(0);
console.log(res);
```

`res` contains the final result.

Comment: The `lastIndexOf` seems very suspicious since array elements are objects not strings

Comment: Well spotted! It was a coincidence that my first version with `.lastIndexOf()` worked (as it returned `-1`). I corrected my script. It should now work reliably.